# Recommendation for a local database for PC

Tags: database

What options do I have for a local DB besides SQLite for PC?

It doesn't have to be a SQL db, but could be as well. For now I pretty much need to check the options.

If it has some built in support for C# that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Sql Server is a perfect database match for Windows and C#.

Express edition is free.

Alternatively, have you explored MS Access? For quickly building applications it is unsurpassed; especially with the built-in reporting. Many programmers might mock it (I did once) but nothing comes close to the built-in functionality.

Comment: Isn't is more suited for a regular DB usage? I want a local db which can be deployed easily and doesn't require a network connection to access

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, and specifically, don't understand what you see as the blockers or problems. I'm not sure if you have tried to deploy Sql Server or Access, and if you have, what are the problems you faced?

Can you explain your situation and the scenario you have in mind?

Comment: Should be light weighted and not require network access